# React native: Android soft keyboard push the View up

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, react-native-textinput

I have made one custom animated bottom sheet. It has two snap points. It starts top of the screen, if scroll the Animated card down it will come middle of the screen , again scroll down the card it will come bottom of the screen. If user scroll the Animated Card hard down then it will go all the way bottom. I made this component as a re-useable component.

I have made re-useable **Search component**.

I imported both of the components to the **main-app** component. Inside the **Animated-Bottom-sheet** I put the **Search-component**.

I have made condition for **keyboard** and **Animated.View**

- If the Animated view move from middle to bottom of the screen and search **onFocus**(keyboard appear) then **Keyboard** will dismiss.
- If Animated View is Bottom of the screen and search input `onfocus`(keyboard appear) then it will move the Animated View middle of the screen. For this logic, I made `Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide',()=>{....})`

**My this logic works perfectly in IOS but in Android, it push all elements top of the screen.**

There is lots of suggestion about KeyboardAvoidingView but in my case, it does not work.

In react-native's android's AndroidManifest.xml file. I made `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and it listen the `Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide'` and push all the elements top of the screen, if I make `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` then it does not listen the `Event-lister`. As a result, My logic does not work and it hides the Animated View under Android Keyboard. According to [RN-documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard), Event-lister only listen `adjustResize or adjustPan`.

### Issue:

**I REALLY DON'T KNOW HOW TO FIX THIS ISSUE**

#### Android Device behavior

[DEMO](https://res.cloudinary.com/drewzxzgc/image/upload/v1633698633/nslkofkivejigfyiag4w.gif)

#### Code-Demo

[expo-snacks](https://snack.expo.dev/@alakdam/keyboard-condition)

**This is is my Animated View component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, Platform, View, Keyboard } from "react-native";
import {
  PanGestureHandler,
  PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

import Animated, {
  useAnimatedGestureHandler,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
  withSpring,
  runOnJS,
  Easing,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const IPHONE_DEVICE_MIDDLE_SCREEN = Platform.OS === "ios" ? 4 : 4;
const IPHONE_DEVICE_BOTTOM_SCREEN = Platform.OS === "ios" ? 7.6 : 7.36;
const ANIMATED_DURATION = 300;

const LoadingContainer = styled.View`
  height: ${SCREEN_HEIGHT - 300}px;
  background-color: #fff;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const ScrollBottomSheet = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const contentTop = useSharedValue(SCREEN_HEIGHT);
  const [bottomSheetState, setBottomSheetState] = useState("top");
  // Event-listener
  Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", () => {
    if (bottomSheetState === "bottom") {
      contentTop.value = withSpring(
        SCREEN_HEIGHT * IPHONE_DEVICE_MIDDLE_SCREEN
      );
    }
  });
  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    "worklet";
    return {
      top: contentTop.value * 0.1,
      bottom: 0,
    };
  });

  const gestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler(
    {
      onStart(_, context) {
        context.translateY = contentTop.value;
      },
      onActive(event, context) {
        contentTop.value = context.translateY + event.translationY;
      },
      onEnd(event, _) {
        if (event.y > 0 && event.y < 200) {
          // MIDDLE SCREEN LOGIC
          contentTop.value = withTiming(
            SCREEN_HEIGHT * IPHONE_DEVICE_MIDDLE_SCREEN,
            {
              duration: ANIMATED_DURATION,
              easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
            }
          );
          runOnJS(setBottomSheetState)("middle");
          runOnJS(Keyboard.dismiss)(); // dismiss Keyboard
        } else if (event.y > 200) {
          // BOTTOM SCREEN LOGIC
          contentTop.value = withTiming(
            SCREEN_HEIGHT * IPHONE_DEVICE_BOTTOM_SCREEN,
            {
              duration: ANIMATED_DURATION,
              easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
            }
          ); 
         runOnJS(Keyboard.dismiss)();
          runOnJS(setBottomSheetState)("bottom");
        } else if (event.translationY < 0) {
          contentTop.value = withTiming(SCREEN_HEIGHT, {
            duration: ANIMATED_DURATION,
            easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
          });
          runOnJS(setBottomSheetState)("top");
        }
      },
    },
    [contentTop]
  );

  return (
    <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.container, animatedStyle]}>
        <View style={styles.grbber} />
        {children}
      </Animated.View>
    </PanGestureHandler>
  );
};

export default ScrollBottomSheet;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    shadowOffset: {
      height: -6,
      width: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    borderTopEndRadius: 15,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
  },
  grbber: {
    width: 80,
    height: 5,
    marginBottom: 4,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginTop: 5,
    borderTopWidth: 5,
    borderTopColor: "#aaa",
  },
});
```

**Search Component**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Animated,
  KeyboardTypeOptions,
  TextInputProps,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  Keyboard,
} from "react-native";

import styled from "styled-components/native";

type Props = TextInputProps & {
  text: string,
  hint: string,
  onChangeText?: ((text: string) => void) | undefined,
  onClearText: () => void,
  animatedStyle?: { height: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation },
  keyboardType?: KeyboardTypeOptions,

  autoFocus?: boolean,
};

const Container = styled(Animated.View)`
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 6px;
  align-items: center;
`;

const IconTouchableOpacity = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  padding: 16px;
`;

const SearchInput = styled.TextInput`
  flex: 1;
  padding-right: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 44px;
`;

const SearchBar = ({
  text,
  hint,
  onChangeText,
  onClearText,
  animatedStyle,
  keyboardType,
  maxLength,
  autoFocus,
}: Props) => {
  const searchInput = useRef(null);

  const onSearchPress = () => {
    searchInput?.current?.focus();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (autoFocus) {
      onSearchPress();
    }
  }, [autoFocus]);

  return (
    <Container accessible={false} style={animatedStyle}>
      <SearchInput
        ref={searchInput}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={text}
        placeholder={hint}
        maxLength={maxLength}
        underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
        placeholderTextColor={"grey"}
        keyboardType={keyboardType}
        autoFocus={autoFocus}
        onKeyPress={() => hideKeyBoard}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

**App Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import { TouchableHighlight } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ScrollBottomSheet from "./components/ActionSheet";
import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";

const initialRegion = {
  latitudeDelta: 15,
  longitudeDelta: 15,
  latitude: 60.1098678,
  longitude: 24.7385084,
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MapView style={styles.mapStyle} initialRegion={initialRegion} />
      <ScrollBottomSheet>
        <SearchContainer>
          <SearchBar hint={"search"} />
        </SearchContainer>
      </ScrollBottomSheet>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapStyle: {
    height: "100%",
  },
});

const SearchContainer = styled.View`
  padding: 10px;
`;
```

Comment: How you tried using `KeyboardAvoidingView`? What behavior did you define? I faced a similar problem and it helped me to define the behavior property as height - `<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={'height'} enable={true}>{/*...*/}</KeyboardAvoidingView>`

Comment: KeyboardTypeOptions from 'react-native' ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Animated.ScrollView instead Animated.View?

Comment: No, I have not use `Animated.ScrollView`.  How It helps in my case